# Can Telegram's bots run python scripts?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to create a bot that scraps all images from a website and send them to me in return.

What I had thought was to make a python scraper with BeautifulSoup that gets the url images and then use the function bot.send_photo(chat_id, 'your URl') in a forloop with every url.

The thing is I actually don't know if this can be done in this way or if it has to use only the telegram's functions to work on mobile.

Comment: The bot's code will be running on the server, so yes, it can be done. Or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: If you're talking about Telegram bots being able to use Python and Python scripts then yes because Telegram has a bot API for Python. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah, I want to know if the bot could read and execute the code with the libraries, as BeautifulSoup and such, with no problem in mobile devices or another device without python and just telegram

Comment: @MiguelArrieche As I said bot's code is running on the server, not on the mobile device.